# ElasticSearch - how to SUM function_score by field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that is using function_score to rank the results.  Here is a sample of what is returned:

```
 {
    "_index": "clone",
    "_type": "authEvent",
    "_id": "6431823",
    "_score": 4.8,
    "fields": {
       "authInput.uID": "MPXWDKW2P",
       "authResult.productValue": 1,
       "authInput.userName": "F936F3AA-E26C-48DB-BDBC-44956B634260",
       "authResult.authEventDate": "2014-02-27T09:29:30.703125-06:00",
       "authResult.rulesFailed": [
          "AuthCountByUser"
       ]
    }
 }
```

What I want to is take the results and run the equivalent of this SQL statement:

```
SELECT TOP 20 "authInput.userName", SUM("_score")
FROM foo
GROUP BY "authInput.userName"
ORDER BY SUM("_score") DESC
```

How can I do this with ES?
NOTE: I'm using ES 0.9x, we will be moving to 1.0.0 soon but we have not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use a facet query to get the total of the amount returned in the query where the facet contains the field where you need the count